# XML to JSON using Jackson 2.6.8 not working as expected

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson

Spec : 10Mb XML,Jackson 2.6.8,jdk1.7

Ref URL :
a) [Convert XML with duplicate elements to JSON using jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427076/convert-xml-with-duplicate-elements-to-json-using-jackson)

b)[How to convert XML to JSON using only Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493173/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-using-only-jackson)

This conversion was not completely in converting XML of size 10Mb to Json.
some of the data was missing.

Any update thoughts , would be appreciated.

Comment: Any error message? Did you set the Logging level to INFO or DEBUG?

Comment: No Error  in logs... but the Json generated  does not have all of the tag and values from XML

Comment: explain what kind of data is missing?

Comment: Sample Test.xml : 
<default><column>
<title>Title 1</title>
<id>id1</id>
<value>val1</value>
</column><column>
<title>Title 2</title>
<id>id2</id>
<value>val2</value>
</column><column>
<title>Title 3</title>
<id>id3</id>
<value>val3</value>
</column>
</default> 
O/p converted Test.json resulted in the following json 
{"column":{"title":"Title 3","id":"id3","value":"val3"}}
The Tags and values missing and code used
xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
node = xmlMapper.readTree(xmlContent);
String jsonContent = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(node)